# Manage Billing permission permission set

Tags: permission-sets, system-permissions

Can anyone please tell me the API name for manage billing system permission?

Comment: The label "Manage Billing" maps to the user permission with the developername "EditBillingInfo"

Comment: @Swetha Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome. I've posted this information as an answer so it can help others in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the label "Manage Billing" maps to the user permission with the developername "EditBillingInfo".

On a general note, you can fetch the label using the below code.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
System.debug(schemaMap.get('SOBJECT_API_NAME_HERE').getDescribe().getLabel());
```